Roboflow Vs. Darknet for generating weight file and creating the model
I have a YoloV8 data file format that is an annotation of data (images) done manually.
What is the most effective and straightforward way of generating a model and therefore yielding the weights file? is it using darknet through the command:
darknet.exe detector train data/obj.data yolo-obj.cfg backup\yolo-obj_2000.weights

then something like the following to generate the associate model:
python tools/model_converter/convert.py cfg/yolov3.cfg weights/yolov3.weights weights/yolov3.h5

Or using Roboflow through:
version.deploy(model_type="yolov8", model_path=f”{HOME}/runs/detect/train/”)

Seems to me darknet is more difficult to install.

The build and installation steps for darknet are very well documented.  Make sure you are using the most recent version of Darknet/YOLO:  https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet#table-of-contents
If you find the steps difficult or lacking in any way, please let me know on the Darknet/YOLO discord server so I can fix or better document whatever you didn't understand:  https://discord.gg/zSq8rtW
Note the recommended training command on the repo and in the Darknet/YOLO FAQ (https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#training_command) is not exactly the command you state.

You left out the very critical parameter -map
You wouldn't normally specify the weights file yolo-obj_2000.weights unless you are resuming training from the 2000th iteration.

Make sure you understand the license difference between v8-9-10, and the completely free and open-source license of Darknet/YOLO.
Lastly, you may want to see this recent video which compares some of the more recent versions of YOLO against the original Darknet/YOLO:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Mq23LFv1aM
Disclaimer:  I maintain the Darknet/YOLO codebase.  I'm the author of tools such as DarkHelp and DarkMark.

I suppose this will generate the model (which would be in which format?): darknet detector -map -dont_show train ~/nn/animals/animals.data ~/nn/animals/animals.cfg  ? THen how to get the associated weights file? for Roboflow do you get the model using the stated command ? if yes how to get the weights (or vise versa)?

Darknet generates the usual Darknet/YOLO .weights files.
